# Skip duplicate async messages

Tags: symfony

I'm using symfony 4.4 with the symfony/messenger in async mode with doctrine as datasource.

The web application dispatch async messages after some user actions. But sometimes, the user execute the same action multiple times, for example, Update the customer.

In this case, if the user update the customer 10 times, the message is sent 10 times, And the worker execute all messages, and the last message alone was sufficient.

Is there a way to optimize and execute only the last message?

Thank's for your help.

Comment: How about just to restrict multiple button clicks?

Comment: So, just seems that you some problems in the implementation. If these 10 actions is same - you should restrict it, but if these 10 actions is not same - you should handle each of them.

Comment: Thanks @EvgenyRuban, the actions are the same, and I hoped there was an easy way to skip them. The solution I implemented is to check if there is the same message in the message table waiting to be handled, and if it is the case, I don't dispatch a new message

Comment: I think the Solution Is on user interface, disallowing repeated requests